# Proc report- grouping

Tags: sas

I have an easy table, and I need to create a complicated report. I tried to do it with proc report using lots of grouping but didn't give me right result. Here is my example table :

```
 campus   id    year   gender
  West    35    2013    F
  West    35    2014    F
  West    35    2015    F
  West    38    2014    M
  West    38    2015    M
  East    48    2014    -
  East    48    2015    -
  East    55    2013    F
  East    55    2014    F
```

And this is the report I need to create:

```
               west             east    
           2014   2015      2014    2015
    total     2      2        2      1

    Gender    2      2        2      1
     F        1      1        1      -
     M        1      1        -      - 
     none     -      -        1      1
```

So I have 4 different group: I worked on this code

```
  proc tabulate data=a ; 
 class gender year ; 
  table gender, year*n*f=4. ; 
   by id;
   run ;
```

Do you think I can do total first, then gender. And tehn I can append them?

Comment: Can you post the proc report code you've tried, that didn't work?

Comment: Or do you think we can do total first, then gender part. And then append it?

Comment: Please add the code to the question via an edit rather than the comments.

Comment: I added, please check and let me know. How can I find that solution. Please. Thank you so much @Reeza

Comment: Any suggestion? If you think this is not a good question, please advise any website or something. Please I need some suggestion.

Comment: @Reeza for all your help. Noones respond, no ones suggest anything. Thank you

Comment: Your data doesn't match your output, you have 2013. I think your expectations of what to expect in terms of time for answers is high.  This is a volunteer forum, people answer as they have time and desire. As a personal choice, I avoid questions with high urgency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't quite match your requested output, but I'm not sure having the total repeated makes sense either. Proc Tabulate works well here:

```
proc tabulate data=have;
class campus year gender/missing;
table (all='Total' gender='Gender'), campus=''*year=''*n='';
run;
```

Comment: Hi Reeza. Is there any way that I can put percentage for all value at the right? And add difference between some terms?

Comment: Hi Reeza. Is there any way that I can put percentage for all value at the right? And add difference between some terms?

Comment: You can add percentage but you can't add difference between terms. If you want difference, I suggest using a data step to define your table and then display it using proc report.

Comment: can you give me a sample?